# React JS: How to pass an array from firebase in query parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using multiselection in one of my parameters and I would like to know how to query those parameters like for example if

I want to query parameters that has 1 (doesn't matter if there are other values)

Value one has : 1, 2, 3
Value two has: 5, 1, 6
Value three has: 5, 6, 9

It should only bring Value one and two

I know you can do something like (for non array values):

```
const librosRef = db.collection('libros');
const queryRef = librosRef.where('grado', '==', '4° Grado');
```

and it would bring all the documents in that collection that has `4° Grado` but if I try to do that while using a multiselection it doesn't bring anything.

This is what I'm trying (doesn't work for array which is what I'm trying to figure out):

```
const productosRef = db.collection('productosAIB');
    const queryRef = productosRef.where('grado', '==', '4° Grado');

    useEffect(() => {
        queryRef.orderBy("precio")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
              const tempData = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

              const data = doc.data();
              tempData.push(data);
            });
            setProductos(tempData);
          });
      }, []);
```

Example of how it gets stored in the Firebase:

[image]

And this is how it looks in the table (without the query because if I add the query it doesn't show anything )

[image]

Comment: Please show an example of your Firestore document

Comment: Oh I forgot about it, I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to query for documents based on the existence of a value in an array. These are called array membership queries in Firestore.

For this, you would use `array-contains` to match a single field in an array, and `array-contains-any` to match any value from an array.

To query based on single value in array

```js
const queryRef = productosRef.where('grado', 'array-contains', '4° Grado');
```

multiple values passed in as an array

```js
const queryRef = productosRef.where('grado', 'array-contains-any', ['4° Grado', 'next array element']);
```

NOTE: array-contains-any can support up to 10 comparison values.

For more information on array membership queries you can see the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: I'll check the documentation, Edit: for some reason it doesn't show up anything in the 4th grade even though I have 2 values, 1 alone and one with multiple values.

Comment: Found my issue apparently I'm not suppose to try and order. As soon as I removed the .orderBy("precio") it worked perfectly, thank you now I have to figure it out why I can't order by price lol

Comment: @ReactPotato can you show your query and also try logging out the data to the console

Comment: My query: `const queryRef = productosRef.where('grado', 'array-contains-any',['4° Grado']); `

Comment: My code in the use effect: `queryRef.get() This works | queryRef.orderBy("precio").get() Doesn't work but doesn't crash | queryRef.get().orderBy("precio") doesn't work and crash `

Comment: @ReactPotato without seeing the full code in context it's difficult to take a guess as to why it's not working. Since this appears to be a separate issue, I recommend creating a new question for it